# Rename command can't handle [ and ( characters?

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename

I have a lot of files with [] characters in them and I wanted to remove them with the following command:

```
rename 's/[xy]/xy/' *
```

Comment: Place \ in front of these symbols.

Comment: or use `rename.ul`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run this command this way

```
rename 's/\[xy\]/xy/' *
```

You need to escape special symbols by backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu of `rename` is written in Perl.
It requires regular expression of Perl.
"`[`" escaped with "`\`".

```
# remove one pair
rename -n 's/\[(.*)\]/$1/' *

# remove all [ and ]
rename -n 's/\[|\]//g' *
```